# Add html code with a function when button is pressed

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to insert some code thanks to a submit button.
To sum up, I want for this button to call an PHP function which adds a block of HTML code. Here is my function:

```
function ajouterStag(){
print_r('<form method="post" action="AjoutFormation.php">
            <label>Nom d\'un stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireNom"/><br/>             
            <label>Mail du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireMail"/><br/>
            <label>Telephone du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireTel"/><br/>
        </form>');
}
```

And here is how I use it:

```
            <h5>Et ses employés ?</h5>
            <label>Nom d'un stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireNom"/><br/>              
            <label>Mail du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireMail"/><br/>
            <label>Telephone du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireTel"/><br/>
        <form method="post" action="AjoutFormation.php">
            <?php ajouterStag(); ?> //Right there
            <input type="submit" value="Ajouter un stagiaire"/>
        </form>
```

In result, I just have the same labels (the tree you can see) twice and my button does nothing.
I'm a beginner in PHP and don't see how to do that.

Do you mind help me?

Comment: `Form` inside a `form` is an invalid markup.

Comment: The function is doing what exactly it is supposed to do. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: @Kumar i want my button to call the function to add the code when in need it.

Comment: @Fefil Call me Praveen! See my answer.

Comment: @u_mulder rly ? it wont work ?

Comment: @Fefil Yup, it won't work. That's invalid HTML. Forms cannot be nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you want something like, repeating additional form elements, you should be using **JavaScript** for that. This is something like a start using jQuery (an awesome JS library):

```js
$(function () {
  $(".add").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).before('<label>Nom d\'un stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireNom"/><br/><label>Mail du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireMail"/><br/><label>Telephone du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireTel"/><br/><br/>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<h5>Et ses employés ?</h5>
<form method="post" action="AjoutFormation.php">
  <label>Nom d'un stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireNom[]"/><br/>              
  <label>Mail du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireMail[]"/><br/>
  <label>Telephone du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireTel[]"/><br/>
  <br/><a href="#" class="add">Add Another Set</a><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Ajouter un stagiaire"/>
</form>
```

While using the above way, you need to send the data to the server in an array way. Like above. See the `name` for all the input elements.

Let me know if this is what you want?

---

> I'm trying to insert some code thanks to a submit button. To sum up, I want that this button call an PHP function which add a block of HTML code.

PHP is a server side language, which gets executed before the client side code renders. This is not possible with PHP, but you need to use some client side programming language such as JavaScript.

For this, you can simply load the file with the form elements hidden and the on the click of a button, you can make it display with JavaScript.

```html
<h5>Et ses employés ?</h5>
<form method="post" action="AjoutFormation.php">
<div style="display: none;" id="hidform">
  <label>Nom d'un stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireNom" /><br/>
  <label>Mail du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireMail" /><br/>
  <label>Telephone du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireTel" /><br/>
  </div>
  <a href="#" onclick="hidform.style.display = 'block'; return false;">Show Form</a><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Ajouter un stagiaire" />
</form>
```

Comment: I suggest dont rely on javascript - it wont be rendered always, as you are depending on browser capabilities.

Comment: @Simos Agreed boss. `:)`

Comment: Thanks but first : i dont understand anything of js xD and secondly : your solution show the labels just ones. i want to show them as many time i want

Comment: @Fefil So you want something like repeating labels, is it? Like add more button? In that case, **you need to use JavaScript**. I can teach you how to make it. Just tell me if that's the case.

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis Looks like the OP has to have a JavaScript solution. Can you see the above comment?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes i see my friend, it was not clearly stated before. You can have a hidden input that will increment every time the form is clicked, so it'll save the number of times to show the labels. I dont know if I understood exactly the situation though.

Comment: Yes exactly ! but i dont understand one thing in your javscript code...

Comment: @Fefil Tell me what you don't understand. I'll clarify you.

Comment: Is it ok if i use PHP and JS in the same page ?

Comment: @Fefil yes yes. Totally fine... PHP is server side and JavaScript is client side.

Comment: The `href="#"`, can i change it or it's the way i have to write this ?

Comment: Thank you a lot but it dont work :( when i click on the link nothing happen i'll edit my post to show you my hole page

Comment: @Fefil Send us the whole page?

Comment: Oh sry ! yeah i couldnt because the "ctrl-K" was broken but i solved my problem with PHP. thanks for helping !

Answer (score -1):

First remove the HTML from your html so we control it through your php function.

Remove this:

```
<h5>Et ses employés ?</h5>
            <label>Nom d'un stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireNom"/><br/>              
            <label>Mail du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireMail"/><br/>
            <label>Telephone du stagiaire : </label><input type="text" name="ajoutStagiaireTel"/><br/>
```

Secondly in change your `<?php ajouterStag(); ?>` so it is checking if the button was clicked.

So it'll become `<?php if(@$_POST) { ajouterStag(); } ?>`

That way the function that displays the HTML code will run only if button is posted.

So your final code would be :

```
<?php if(@$_POST) { ajouterStag();  } ?> 
<form method="post" action="AjoutFormation.php">        
    <input type="submit" value="Ajouter un stagiaire"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I dont understand one thing : you say i have to remove my form tags but where should i put them ?

Comment: Sorry i'm not understood clearly. You have to remove your h5 and labels, since we will output them from php if button is submitted.  The form tags will remain as they are.

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis Someone down-voted your answer, and it's definitely not me. `:(`